# How to write the formula of Sum of Squared Deviation with SD and n in R?

Tags: sample

mathematical formula to calculate standard deviation is
$SD = (\frac{SSD}{n-1})^{0.5}$

Would like to find SSD and how to write in r ?

SSD = ????

Comment: Just rearrange: `ssd <- (sd^2)*(n-1)`.

Comment: @ralph thanks ralph! but can you show the working to convert that to sd^2?

Comment: Square both sides (to remove the square root), then multiply both sides by $(n - 1)$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use $\sigma$ for SD to avoid confusion with SSD:

If $\sigma = (\frac{SSD}{n-1})^{0.5}$, then

$\sigma^2 = \frac{SSD}{n-1}$. Therefore:

$SSD = \sigma^2  (n-1)$

Comment: So sd(x)^2 * (length(x) - 1) in R (or var(x) * (length(x) - 1))